# Using vectors in Visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I was able to solve most errors, but somehow I couldn't figure this out. I saw a few posts about using vectors, but I am not sure of it.Any help appreciated.

Visual studio tells me that the expression must have a constant value

EDIT: I KNOW I'm not using a vector, I was asking about it

```
const int ptarraysize = 256;
EC_POINT *ppnt[ptarraysize];
```

Comment: You're code uses an array, not a `vector`.  To actually use a vector: `std::vector<EC_POINT*> ppnt(ptarraysize);` (for which you'll need `#include <vector>` atop the file).

Comment: In the small code you posted, the compiler should have been able to make `ptarraysize` a compile-time constant. Is that your actual code? Can you perhaps  create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which have the problems you have, and show that to us, together with the actual errors?

Comment: As for actual *vectors*, try [this `std::vector` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). Most of the functions should have small examples showing how they are used.

Comment: Well, this code works fine in gcc.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg The code is minimal and complete here. The compiler didn't make it a compile time constant which is why the question

Comment: @TonyD I was actually asking about using vectors, thank you

Comment: @Deqing I'm quite surprised too, I was able to compile it in Linux

Comment: @Sajidkhan: sure - no worries.  Re Linux/GCC - it has a non-Standard extension that allows arrays of dynamic (run-time specified) size, unlike VC++ which sticks to the Standard.  If you use `g++ -pedantic` it will warn you about use of such non-Standard features.   Re minimal/complete: `EC_POINT` isn't declared so it's not a complete, valid program.

Comment: @Sajidkhan: you obviously don't understand what's meant by minimal and complete *in this context*: did you carefully read the link Joachim provided in the second comment above?  Summarily, *we* can't cut-and-paste your code into any C++ compiler and expect it to compile: if will choke on `EC_POINT`.  That you have it declared somewhere doesn't help other people reproduce your problem, or test solutions to it.

Comment: @TonyD You don't want to help, you want to be right. This is a pretty theoretical question and I find absolutely no need to "reproduce the problem". Get off your high horse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++, we use [std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) for fixed size containers:

```
#include <array>

const int ptarraysize = 256;
std::array<EC_POINT*, ptarraysize> ppnt;
```

Comment: Thank you, I managed to crack the program using this!

Comment: This is only for C++11.

Comment: @Shreevardhan C++11 is the current standard.

Answer (score 1):

This is not even a vector, you are declaring and array, to use a vector you need to type `std::vector<EC_POINT*> ppnt(ptarraysize)`
This will create a vector of size 256 and initialize the values with the default constructor of the class.